# Computing limit of $\sqrt{n^2+n}-\sqrt[4]{n^4+1}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, analysis, limits

I have tried to solve this using conjugate multiplication, but I got stuck after factoring out $n^2$.

$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{n^2+n-\sqrt{n^4+1}}{\sqrt{n^2+n}+\sqrt[4]{n^4+1}}
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{n(1+\dfrac{1}{n}-\sqrt{1+\dfrac{1}{n^4}})}{\sqrt{1+\dfrac{1}{n}}+\sqrt[4]{1+\dfrac{1}{n^4}}}\\&
=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{n+1-n\sqrt{1+\dfrac{1}{n^4}}}{\sqrt{1+\dfrac{1}{n}}+\sqrt[4]{1+\dfrac{1}{n^4}}}
\end{align}$

Given that $\dfrac{1}{n}$ tends to $0$ (so denominator is 2), can I reduce $n$ and $-n\sqrt{1+\dfrac{1}{n^4}}$ and say that the limit is $\dfrac{1}{2}$?

I mean $\dfrac{1}{n^4}$ tends to $0$, so $\sqrt{1+\dfrac{1}{n^4}}$ tends to $1$ and in this case $n-n\sqrt{1+\dfrac{1}{n^4}}$ can be simplified to $n-n$.

Solution given in my book uses conjugate multiplication twice to get rid of all the roots in nominator, but I am curious if my answer is correct or my teacher will tell me that simplifying the way I did it is incorrect.

Comment: Well, you can reduce that you say ... **if**  ... you prove it. As far as I can see it you can't.

Comment: i think there is a typo in your calculation, a square root in your first term hase changed to the $$\sqrt[4]{..}$$

Comment: What about systematic approaches, such as using the fact that, for every $a$, when $x\to0$, $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(1+x)^a-1}x=a$$ Hence, using $$(n^2+n)^{1/2}-(n^4+1)^{1/4}=n\left((1+1/n)^{1/2}-1\right)-n^{-3}\cdot n^4\left((1+1/n^4)^{1/4}-1\right)$$ one sees that the first term on the RHS converges to $\frac12$ and the second term on the RHS converges to $0$, hence you are done.

Comment: Your result is true, your reasoning isn't, because you could as well say $\sqrt{n^2+n}-n=n\sqrt{1+1/n}-n$ can be simplified to $n-n$, and that's not true.

Comment: To make your reasoning work you have to also provide a bound on $\sqrt{1+n^{-4}}$; for instance, you know that it is $\geq 1$ (why?) and $\leq 1+n^{-4}$ (also why?), and using these together you can bound your numerator from either side and then squeeze it.

Comment: @Did: why not make that into an answer? It is a good approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(n-n\sqrt{1+\frac1{n^4}}\right)=0$. You cannot simply use that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{1+\frac1{n^4}}=1$ since $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{1+\frac1n}=1$, yet $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(n-n\sqrt{1+\frac1n}\right)=-\frac12$.

---

If you are looking for an alternate approach, note that $a^4-b^4=(a-b)\left(a^3+a^2b+ab^2+b^3\right)$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{n^2+n}-\sqrt[4]{n^4+1}
&=\frac{\left(n^2+n\right)^2-\left(n^4+1\right)}{\scriptsize\left(n^2+n\right)^{3/2}+\left(n^2+n\right)\left(n^4+1\right)^{1/4}+\left(n^2+n\right)^{1/2}\left(n^4+1\right)^{1/2}+\left(n^4+1\right)^{3/4}}\\
&=\frac{2+\frac1n-\frac1{n^3}}{\scriptsize\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{3/2}+\left(1+\frac1n\right)\left(1+\frac1{n^4}\right)^{1/4}+\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{1/2}\left(1+\frac1{n^4}\right)^{1/2}+\left(1+\frac1{n^4}\right)^{3/4}}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 3):

One simple method is to try adding terms to give upper and lower bounds for the given roots. One may confirm (and not hard to find, either)
$$ \left( n + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{8n} \right)^2 < n^2 + n < \left( n + \frac{1}{2}  \right)^2 $$
$$ n^4 < n^4 + 1 < \left( n + \frac{1}{4n^3}   \right)^4 $$
Together, we get
$$ \frac{1}{2} -  \frac{1}{8n} - \frac{1}{4n^3} \; \;  < \; \; \sqrt{n^2+n}-\sqrt[4]{n^4+1} \; \; < \; \; \frac{1}{2}  $$
Some people call this the Squeeze Theorem, the limit is $\frac{1}{2} $

Answer (score 2):

it must be $$\frac{(n^2+n)^2-(n^4+1)}{(\sqrt{n^2+n}+\sqrt[4]{n^4+1})(n^2+n+\sqrt{n^4+1})}$$

Comment: Yes this is what my book is saying. I was curious if my reasoning can be accepted, as this is still a little abstract to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Let $t = \frac1n$

Then use the derivative formula at $t = 0$ , 
$$ \begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n^2+n}-\sqrt[4]{n^4+1} &= \lim_{n\to\infty} n\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}+1}-\sqrt[4]{\frac{1}{n^4}+1}\right)  \\&= \lim_{t\to0}\frac{1}t(\sqrt{t+1}-\sqrt[4]{t^4+1})\\&= \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{t+1}-1}{t} - \frac{\sqrt[4]{t^4+1}-1}{t} \\&=\left(\sqrt{t+1}\right)'\bigg|_{t =0 } -\left(\sqrt[4]{t^4+1}\right)'\bigg|_{t =0 }= \frac{1}{2}\end{align} $$